# Flask Tutorial - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am working through the Flask tutorial for creating a basic blog application.  I have gotten through the Blog Blueprint section and I am getting the AttributeError: NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute' the error points to this

> File "/home/ridgfam/python/projects/flaskr/blog.py", line 14, in index
> posts = db.execute(
> ^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

I've been back through and rechecked and rechecked everything and cannot find an error, as soon as I login to the application I get that error.

Below is the code for the blog.py and auth.py

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
)
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort

from flaskr.auth import login_required
from flaskr.db import get_db

bp = Blueprint('blog', __name__)

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    db = get_db()
    posts = db.execute(
        'SELECT p.id, title, body, created, author_id, username'
        ' FROM post p JOIN user u ON p.author_id = u.id'
        ' ORDER BY created DESC'
    ).fetchall()
    return render_template('blog/index.html', posts=posts)

@bp.route('/create', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        body = request.form['body']
        error = None
        
        if not title:
            error = 'Title is required'
            
        if error is not None:
            flash(error)
        else:
            db = get_db()
            db.execute(
                'INSERT INTO post (title, body, author_id)'
                ' VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
                (title, body, g.user['id'])
            )
            db.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('blog.index'))
        
    return render_template('blog/create.html')

def get_post(id, check_author=True):
    post = get_db().execute(
        'SELECT p.id, title, body, created, author_id, username'
        ' FROM post p JOIN user u ON p.author_id = u.id'
        ' WHERE p.id = ?',
        (id,)
    ).fetchone()
    
    if post is None:
        abort(404, f"Post id {id} doesn't exist.")
        
    if check_author and post['author_id'] != g.user['id']:
        abort(403)
        
    return post

@bp.route('/<int:id>/update', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def update(id):
    post = get_post(id)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        body = r`your text`equest.form['body']
        error = None
        
        if not title:
           
 error = 'Title is required.'
            
        if error is not None:
            flash(error)
        else:
            db = get_db()
            db.execute(
                'UPDATE post SET title = ?, body = ?'
                ' WHERE id = ?',
                (title, body, id)
            )
            db.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('blog.index'))
        
    return render_template('blog/update.html', post=post)

@bp.route('/<int:id>/delete', methods=('POST',))
@login_required
def delete(id):
    get_post(id)
    db = get_db()
    db.execute('DELETE FROM post WHERE id = ?', (id,))
    db.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('blog.index'))
```

```
import functools

from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
)
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from flaskr.db import get_db

bp = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')

@bp.route('/register', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db = get_db()
        error = None
        
        if not username:
            error = 'Username is required.'
        elif not password:
            error = 'Password is required.'
            
        if error is None:
            try:
                db.execute(
                    'INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)',
                    (username, generate_password_hash(password)),
                )
                db.commit()
            except db.IntegrityError:
                error = f'Usser {username} is already registered.'
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
            
        flash(error)
            
    return render_template('auth/register.html')
    
@bp.route('/login', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db = get_db()
        error = None
        user = db.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', (username,)
        ).fetchone()
        
        if user is None:
            error = 'Incorrect username.'
        elif not check_password_hash(user['password'], password):
            error = 'Incorrect password.'
            
        if error is None:
            session.clear()
            session['user_id'] = user['id']
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
            
        flash(error)
        
    return render_template('auth/login.html')
    
@bp.before_app_request
def load_logged_in_user():
    user_id = session.get('user_id')
    
    if user_id is None:
        g.user = None
    else:
        g.user = get_db().execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', (user_id,)
        ).fetchone()
        
@bp.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

def login_required(view):
    @functools.wraps(view)
    def wrapped_view(**kwargs):
        if g.user is None:
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
        
        return view(**kwargs)
    
    return wrapped_view
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `get_db` function is not returning a valid reference. You should have a *db.py* module that implements it. See [Define and Access the Database](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/database/).

Comment: I do have a db.py module as well and have been able to initialize the database following that same documentation.

Comment: Then for some reason the call to `get_db` is not returning a valid reference. You will need to do some debugging to find out why. I have followed this same tutorial in the past so I know it works.